# Insert data into array [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift

First of all I'm sorry for my poor english!
I have a question about inserting value into arrays by using Apple Swift language.
I am absolutely new at Swift and iOS development, so I have to say SORRY one more time.

I have a plist file and a method to read it and convert data to NSDictionary. This data I use in Picker.

PLIST File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Years</key>
    <array>
        <string>2010</string>
        <string>2011</string>
        <string>2012</string>
        <string>2013</string>
        <string>2014</string>
        <string>2015</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And a method for reading and converting:

```
func getList(fileName: String) -> NSDictionary? {
     var myDict: NSDictionary?
     if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "plist") {
         myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
     }
     return myDict?
}
```

Everything is ok. Now I try to convert this data to Array and push it into UIPicker. My array is:

```
var Years = getList("Years")?.objectForKey("Years") as NSArray
```

There is a question: I'm trying to insert data into my array and I've got a few errors. I've tried everything... I'd like to insert new value to zero index, but **insert** method not working, **append** method not working too (NSArray has no this methods, ok). I've tried to use NSMutableArray - nothing. As I know, NSMutableArray has **addObject** and **insertObject** methods, and i 
have got error too *(error: Void is not convertible to NSArray)*

What I do wrong? How can I simply insert value to the end of array and at zero index?

NSArray and ["value", ...] are different things?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Years is actually an NSArray, you can't add anything to it because it's immutable. You need to make a mutable copy,

```
var Years = getList("Years")?.objectForKey("Years") as NSArray
var mutableYears = Years.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
mutableYears.addObject("2016")
mutableYears.insertObject("2009", atIndex:0)
```

You really should start your variable names with a lowercase letter.